# What characters allow white-space: pre-wrap to wrap?

Tags: css

I was surprised to find that my `white-space: pre-wrap;` text is wrapping at `&gt;` and `"` characters. I thought it would only wrap at new lines, `-`, and after one or more spaces.

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/brandoncc/x5bz2ed3/6/).

It wraps after `"`, before `<`. It also wraps after `>`, before `<`.

I can't find anything in the spec that says what characters allow wrapping. It only says "Lines are broken at preserved newline characters, and as necessary to fill line boxes.".

Comment: I think line-break opportunities are a bit of a dark art. As far as I can see, neither CSS nor Unicode define the break opportunities you describe. But I think a lot of it comes down to what's normal for a language. English doesn't have typical situations where it's necessary for meaning to keep `"<` or `><` together, so they're used as line-break opportunities.

Answer (score 2):

The same characters which cause wrapping normally will also cause wrapping with `white-space: pre-wrap;`, with the addition that newlines and whitespace in the text will also cause newlines and whitespace in the output.

Try removing `white-space: pre-wrap;` in your example and you will see that the only change is that there are no longer any blank lines. Otherwise the wrapping behaviour is the same.

See: https://drafts.csswg.org/css-text/#valdef-white-space-pre-wrap

> *pre-wrap:* Like 'pre', this value preserves white space; but like 'normal', it allows wrapping.

For more details about when wrapping can occur normally, see: https://drafts.csswg.org/css-text/#line-breaking